# Python 3 Tkinter: How to word-wrap text in Tkinter Text

Tags: python, tkinter

How do you word-wrap text in a Tkinter `Text` widget? `wraplength` only takes in screen units, and not a `WORD` option.

Comment: a text widget does not have a `wraplength` widget; only Label widgets have that option. Are you asking about a Text widget or a Label widget?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the `wrap=WORD` option. Here's an example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
t = Text(wrap=WORD)
t.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively you can set a value for `wrap` using `Text.config()`:

```
t = Text()
t.config(wrap=WORD)
```

The other valid values for `wrap` are `CHAR` which is the default, or `NONE` in which case no wrapping occurs and the line will grow indefinitely.

Comment: Aweasome! Thnx so much

Comment: for me this needed to be `wrap="word"`

Comment: @botbot: `tkinter.WORD` _is_ `'word'`. You just need to import it: `from tkinter import WORD`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought the normal CHAR wrap looked a little funny in some situations!